# Failing to initialize Nvidia GPU Geforce GTX 650 Ti

Tags: drivers, 13.04, nvidia, xorg

I am unable to use nvidia drivers for my GPU, an Nvida Geforce 650TI since I updated to 13.04. I was using the nouveau drivers, but it became unstable, crashing at least once per day and I need to make the nvidia drivers to work.

When I try logging in, X just crash and prompt me back to the login screen.

in my Xorg.0.log I get :

```
    [    46.837] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
    [    46.837] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
    [    46.837] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
    [    46.837] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    46.837]    compiled for 1.13.3, module version = 1.0.0
    [    46.837]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 7.0
    [    46.837] (==) AIGLX enabled
    [    46.837] Loading extension GLX
    [    46.837] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
    [    46.837] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
    [    46.837] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
    [    46.837]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
    [    46.837]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [    46.837] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  304.88  Wed Mar 27 14:28:14 PDT 2013
    [    46.837] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
    [    46.837] (++) using VT number 7
    [    46.837] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
    [    46.837] (II) LoadModule: 
    [    46.837] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
    [    46.837] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    46.837]    compiled for 1.13.3, module version = 1.0.0
    [    46.837]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
    [    46.837] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
    [    46.837] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
    [    46.837] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
    [    46.838] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    [    46.838]    compiled for 1.13.3, module version = 1.0.0
    [    46.838]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
    [    46.838] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
    [    46.838] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
    [    46.838] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
    [    46.838] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
    [    46.838] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
    [    46.838] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
    [    46.838] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    [    46.838] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
    [    46.838] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the GLX module; please check in your X
    [    46.838] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     log file that the GLX module has been loaded in your X
    [    46.838] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     server, and that the module is the NVIDIA GLX module.  If
    [    46.838] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     you continue to encounter problems, Please try

    [    46.838] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     reinstalling the NVIDIA driver.
```

I tried installing at least 5 different version of the nvidia driver (current, 304, 310,313,319 and 325)

I did recreate my xorg.conf via nvidia-xconfig

Any help would be very appreciated.

It seems my libglx.so is dating from a few months. When I remove it, I can log in, but Unity is not loading. Any methods to update libglx.so for my nvidia drivers?? Are they located somewhere else?

Thanks

Comment: Well my brother has the same video card and I have followed the guide http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers/61433#61433 and the video card is working correctly. Followed the guide for 12.10 and for 13.04 32/64 Bit. Also know that the 600 Series is better with the 319 and 325 drivers (Using the PPA).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best thing to do is install the [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation). Generally it solves all the nvidia drivers issues in a "smooth way".